# Mac: open the files found with grep in sublime

Tags: macos, grep, sublimetext

Its fairly common for me to use the -l flag in greg to get a list of files. I love to have a way to immediately open all of the found files in sublime (with the subl command somehow, I assume) instead of just outputting a list.

My current workflow:

```
grep --include=*.php -R -l "tribe_events_event_classes" .
```

Which outputs:

```
./plugins/events-calendar-pro/views/day/loop.php
./plugins/events-calendar-pro/views/map/loop.php
./plugins/events-calendar-pro/views/photo/loop.php
./plugins/events-calendar-pro/views/widgets/mini-calendar/list.php
./plugins/the-events-calendar/lib/tribe-template-factory.class.php
./plugins/the-events-calendar/public/template-tags/general.php
./plugins/the-events-calendar/views/list/loop.php
./plugins/the-events-calendar/views/month/single-event.php
./themes/roots/tribe-events/day/loop.php
```

Then I usually copy and paste the files one by one with:

```
subl ./plugins/events-calendar-pro/views/day/loop.php
subl ./plugins/events-calendar-pro/views/map/loop.php
etc...
```

I know here has to be a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: I do the opposite. I run search from the sublime. I open ST2 in the current folder (subl .) and then right click the directory on the tree pane and choose Find % Replace. You can give a file mask to ST2 find comma separated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be:

```
subl `grep --include=*.php -R -l "tribe_events_event_classes" .`
```

(note the backticks).

Or:

```bsh
for file in `grep --include=*.php -R -l "tribe_events_event_classes" .`; do
    subl $file
done
```

---

***EDIT***

Since backticks don't nest well, using command substitution is better:

```
subl $(grep --include=*.php -R -l "tribe_events_event_classes" .)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bash script could solve this nicely. Here is an untested concept (may require some tweaking):

```
#!/bin/bash

files=()

while grep --include=*.php -R -l "tribe_events_event_classes" .; do
  files += ("$REPLY")
done

for file in "${files[@]}"; do 
  subl $file 
done
```